# Best way to manage Resellers

Tags: magento2, magento-1, magento-community

I have to implement in Magento CE 1.9 a system for managing our reseller network.

In short, this is the scenario:

- reseller can sell our products using our shop frontend, providing
  to their customers the link of their landing page (ex.
  www.shop.com/reseller-name).
- The Reseller's landing pages are graphically customized, offering
  the main product catalog (or a selection). There is no possibility
  by    the resellers to upload/choose their products.
- Product's prices and features, along resellers commissions, are
  defined by the Admin. Admin can define global values or different
  values for each resellers.
- Resellers earn their commission only when a product is added to
  cart from their landing page/catalog.
- About Payment: money are sent to the Admin, that will pay later the 
  commission to their resellers.
- About Shipping: the Admin ship the goods to the resellers, no need
  to implement a different way to manage the shipment.
- Reseller have a personal backend/dashboard in order to monitoring
  their orders, commissions, customer's addresses, ecc.

The are some great Magento extensions that permit to obtain a Multivendor Market Place (ex. https://www.apptha.com/magento/marketplace or https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace) but they are more powerful than my needs, above all permitting users to create their own shop on your platform, uploading their own products.

I have not yet found any extensions that permit to obtain the described goals, and customizing any Multivendor Market place extension is expensive and finally not an "elegant" solutions.

I also think that using the native Magento multi-store functionalities will lead to a painfull resellers management: I will have to manage a great number of resellers and I need to automatize as much as possible the Sign-Up/selling flow by the resellers.

Do you have any good idea?
Thank you!

Comment: `I also think that using the native Magento multi-store functionalities will lead to a painfull resellers management` you're right about that one. I'm not sure Magento CE is the right solution for that. Don't know about EE though.

Comment: Thank you Julien for your reply. Indeed the multi-store functionalities would be a good choiche only where you need to manage very few Resellers and products (ex. less than 4 Resellers and less than 10 products.)

Comment: I found your question as its exactly what do i need, did you have any chance of found this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157892)

Comment: Magestore discontinued this product from his website and stopped future support i was cheated by this company. currently link not is working https://www.magestore.com/affiliateplus/

Answer (score 1):

Careful evaluations have led us to think that **considering ReSellers as a sort of Sales Agent** should bring to an easier solutions implementation, for example using an extension like this: https://www.cminds.com/ecommerce-extensions-store/sales-rep-commission-manager-extension-for-magento

An alternative way would be to implement an **Affiliate Program** that permit your Resellers to link/show your product on their websites, using an extension like this: https://www.magestore.com/affiliateplus/

The market seems lacking a pure Magento ReSeller Extension, so the third way seems to create an extension from scratch!